# How to fix a triangle of prime numbers

Tags: python

```
n=3

for i in range(5):

    print(2, end=" ")

    for j in range(i):

        for k in range(2,n):

            if (n%k==0):

                n+=1

            else:

                print (n, end=" ")

                n+=1

                break

    n=3

 print()
```

In the code mentioned above , I'm trying to print out prime numbers in a triangle , like :

2

2 3

2 3 5

2 3 5 7

2 3 5 7 11

But , it prints out 10 instead of 11 .

Please help .

In the prime numbers triangle that I was trying to create , I got some composite numbers too in the way .

Say when I put range(15) in 2nd line , I got :

2

2 3

2 3 5

2 3 5 7

2 3 5 7 10

2 3 5 7 10 11

2 3 5 7 10 11 13

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17 19

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17 19 22

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17 19 22 23

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17 19 22 23 25

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17 19 22 23 25 29

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17 19 22 23 25 29 31

2 3 5 7 10 11 13 17 19 22 23 25 29 31 34

I am not able to understand that how do composite numbers , too , come in the triangle , when the code was supposed to print only prime numbers there .

Comment: The issue in your code is that you're only checking divisibility for numbers less than `n`. If `n` is composite but its factors are greater than `n/2`, the code will still think `n` is prime. So, the check for prime numbers is not being done correctly.

Comment: @MikaDior How do you have a number `n`, with a factor greater than `n/2`... can you think of a single example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your code is flawed. These two lines:

```
if (n%k==0):
    n+=1
```

do not reset `k` to `2` after `n` has been detected as not being prime. Therefore, after you increment `n`, `k` continues where it has left off. Furthermore, this statement

```
else:
    print (n, end=" ")
```

means that `n` is automatically assumed as `prime` if the first value of `k` checked is not a factor of `n`. This is incorrect as there may be other values of `k` that are factors of `n` if `n` is composite.

Try something like this instead:

```
n=3

for i in range(5):

    print(2, end=" ")

    for j in range(i):

        ok = False
        
        while not ok:

            ok = True

            for k in range(2,n):

                if (n%k==0):

                    ok = False
                    
                    break
                
            if not ok:
                
                n += 1
                
        print (n, end=" ")
        
        n += 1

    n=3

    print()
```

Here, `ok` tracks if the current value of `n` is prime or not.